# css3 transition issue with chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, webkit, transition

I am working on SVG, an object inside SVG has simple transition style , but it has issue in chrome and it breaks the objects and  it can't show smooth transition.

Do you have any idea?
I Have already read lots of post like this one and none of them helps:
http://www.sitepoint.com/fix-chrome-animation-flash-bug/

These style doesn't change the issue:

`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;   -webkit-transform: scale(1);`

```
<pre>
<style>
.irwild:hover , .comwild:hover , .irstd:hover , .comstd:hover  {
transform: translate(-30px);
-ms-transform: translate(-30px);
-webkit-transform: translate(-30px);}

.irwild , .comwild , .irstd , .comstd  {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;
backface-visibility:     hidden; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;}
</style>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have difficulty animation use -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); to make chrome use hardware acceleration.